# Refreshing input:radio from iframe using Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, iframe, refresh

I'm trying to change the selected option of an input:radio (that is in the main page) dynamically clicking a button inside an iframe. 
To do this, y pass by parameter the variable containing the input:radio element:

```
//code from iframe.js
button.live("click", function(e) { 
    var inputRadioContainer = $(window.parent.document).find('#inputRadioContainer');
    changeInputRadio(inputRadioContainer, "email");
});

//code from mainPage.js
function changeInputRadio(inputRadioContainer, val){
    inputRadioContainer.find('input:radio[value=val]').attr('checked',true).checkboxradio('refresh');
}

//HTML content of inputRadioContainer
<ul id="inputRadioContainer" data-role="listview">
  <li>     
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-role="fieldcontain" data-mini="true">
        <input type="radio" name="radio-contacto" id="radio-contacto-1" value="email"/>
        <label for="radio-contacto-1" value="email">email</label>

        <input type="radio" name="radio-contacto" id="radio-contacto-2" value="tlf"/>
        <label for="radio-contacto-2" value="tlf">telf</label>
    </fieldset>
  </li>
</ul>
```

After executing that code, the "checked" attribute of the required radio is setted to "checked" (as expected), but the radio is not displayed checked. It seems that **".checkboxradio('refresh');"** is not working. I also tried doing **"inputRadioContainer.listview('refresh')"** but it doesn't work.

Anyone knows how to solve the problem?
Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Using
inputRadioContainer.find('input:radio[value=val]').attr('checked',true)**.trigger('click');**

instead of
inputRadioContainer.find('input:radio[value=val]').attr('checked',true)**.checkboxradio('refresh');**

I hope helping someone